# Sublime Text (3) Keymaps Across OS's?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

Has anyone solved the problem of different Sublime Text keymappings across operating systems?

I use Linux, Windows, and occasionally OS X.  And, I have Sublime Text 3 installed on all platforms.  While I don't mind differences between CTRL and CMD, several other key mappings keep biting me . . and, as I use more features, it's getting more and more annoying:

- The emacs keys ctrl-a/ctrl-e for beginning and end of line.

  - Only worked on OS X.  When I remapped them on the other platforms, I lost the ability to select all.
  - Since those keys also work on most unix-ish shells, I use them often.
- Ctrl-S / Cmd-S for saving:  For some reason, I keep hitting ctrl-s on OS X to save.  This is the one Cmd vs Ctrl issue that has been biting me.
- I'm sure there are more . . .

But, since it's annoying me, I'm sure it annoys others, and maybe someone has come up with a solution of some kind?  Maybe a standard keymap, so I'll mess up everywhere until I get used to it?  Maybe put emacs keymaps (or vi keymaps) everywhere?